# MySQL Permissions Over User

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-permissions

My friend has a VPS. He trusts me and more or less will help me do anything I want to do. I am using a number of MySQL users (less privileged) and databases. For example, I am my_user, and I created mydomain_select and mydomain_insert to isolate privileges (since PHP->MySQL passwords in text). Currently I cannot edit any permissions as my user and have to go bother my friend any time I want to change any privileges.

Is there some way he can give my user permissions to alter the permissions of certain other users (USER like 'mydomain_%')? Can I set this up such that I will get the Permissions tab in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change your own username permissions from phpMyAdmin. Only admin username can change it for your username. Update your friend to login to phpMyAdmin using admin login.

1. Click on privileges link.
2. Select your username.
3. Click on "Check All" permissions link.
4. Click on Go button.

Comment: I know I can't edit my own permissions. I want to be able to edit the permissions of **certain** other users. Global permissions are not an option.